# Joining multiple tables into a single mysql table adding new field to each record

Tags: mysql

i have a question about mysql. I have multiple tables (Dresden, dusseldorf, England, etc) each one of this have the following fields (Name, loginname, macaddress). Some users are in more than one table (the same user can be in two or more of this tables.) I want to create a table where i can see all users. I was wondering if it is possible to add a field at the end of each raw telling where if come from and to merge all repeated files. I hope i made myself clear.... i am really new to mysql....

Best regards...

Here are my tables:

Dusseldorf:

```
--------------------------------
|Username | value | macaddress |
-------------------------------
|jose     | 10    | 00:00:00:00|
--------------------------------
|maria    | 20    | 00:00:00:01|
--------------------------------
```

Dresden:

```
--------------------------------
|Username | value | macaddress |
--------------------------------
|jose     | 10    | 00:00:00:00|
--------------------------------
|maria    | 20    | 00:00:00:01|
--------------------------------
|juan     | 15    | 00:00:00:02|
--------------------------------
```

England:

```
--------------------------------
|Username | value | macaddress |
-------------------------------
|jose     | 10    | 00:00:00:00|
-------------------------------
|maria    | 20    | 00:00:00:01|
--------------------------------
|pedro    | 20    | 00:00:00:03|
--------------------------------
```

All together:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|Username | value | macaddress | Dusseldorf | Dresden | England |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|jose     | 10    | 00:00:00:00|     X      |    X    |    X    |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|maria    | 20    | 00:00:00:01|     X      |    X    |    X    |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|juan     | 15    | 00:00:00:02|            |    X    |         |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|pedro    | 20    | 00:00:00:03|            |         |    X    |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: so you want to list all the data from all the tables with the table name from where it comes ?

Comment: yes @abhik-chakraborty i want to merge them all but the tricky part is that in that merge i will get multiple results where the user is the same but the Location is different. I would like to merge those into a single result with multiple Locations....

Comment: so say one user name `xxxx` is from different tables has locations as `aa,bb,cc` from 3 tables and now while merging do you want them as `XXX  aa,bb,cc` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could select this data with several `UNION` statements and use a `CREATE TABLE` to create the new table:

```
CREATE TABLE all_merged AS
 SELECT s.*,
        concat((SELECT 'Dresden' 
                  FROM Dresden
                 WHERE Dresden.name=s.name
                   AND Dresden.loginname = s.loginname
                   AND Dresden.macaddress = s.macaddress
               ),
               (SELECT 'Dusseldorf' 
                  FROM Dusseldorf
                 WHERE Dresden.name=s.name
                   AND Dresden.loginname = s.loginname
                   AND Dresden.macaddress = s.macaddress
               ),
               ...) as `location`
   FROM
        ( SELECT name, loginname,macaddress
            FROM Dresden
           UNION
          SELECT name, loginname,macaddress
            FROM Dusseldorf
           UNION
           ....
        ) AS S
 )
```

Althought I thing that building a view could be better for your case:

```
CREATE VIEW v_all_merged AS
 SELECT s.*,
        concat((SELECT 'Dresden' 
                  FROM Dresden
                 WHERE Dresden.name=s.name
                   AND Dresden.loginname = s.loginname
                   AND Dresden.macaddress = s.macaddress
               ),
               (SELECT 'Dusseldorf' 
                  FROM Dusseldorf
                 WHERE Dresden.name=s.name
                   AND Dresden.loginname = s.loginname
                   AND Dresden.macaddress = s.macaddress
               ),
               ...) as `location`
   FROM
        ( SELECT name, loginname,macaddress
            FROM Dresden
           UNION
          SELECT name, loginname,macaddress
            FROM Dusseldorf
           UNION
           ....
        ) AS S
 )
```

I just created a [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8ca2f/1) to show the solution

Comment: I would suggest to use `UNION ALL`  since the OP wants the duplicate data as well and show it from which table.

Comment: Well, there can be no duplicates as location will be different. But I agree, why use UNION instead of UNION ALL when there are no duplicates to remove?

Comment: True, a `UNION ALL` would be better. I'm going to edit it. Thank-you

Comment: the create view would work but i would get multiple records with the same username and differents Locations. i would like to get only one record with Location beeing the Name of the multiple Locations....

Comment: ahhhh, I did'n understood that with the question.... Let me change the query, then

Comment: SQL create algorithm = undefined view `v_all_merged` as SELECT s.*, concat((SELECT 'dresden' FROM dresden WHERE dresden.name=s.name AND dresden.loginname = s.loginname AND dresden.macaddress = s.macaddress ), (SELECT 'dusseldorf' FROM dusseldorf WHERE dusseldorf.name=s.name AND dusseldorf.loginname = s.loginname AND dusseldorf.macaddress = s.macaddress ), ) as `location` FROM ( SELECT name, loginname, macaddress FROM dresden UNION SELECT name, loginname, macaddress FROM dusseldorf UNION ) AS S )

Comment: failed : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') as `location` FROM ( SELECT name, loginname, macaddress ' at line 1

Comment: @user3615697: As to have all locations in one string: This is no good design. Better have a table of users, a table of locations and a bridge table to relate users and locations.

Comment: sorry for the double posting but the message was too long. When i try to create the view i got that message. can you please tell me what am i doing wrong?

Comment: I see in the error you posted that you wrote `... FROM dusseldorf UNION ) AS S )` this last `UNION` should not be there. On my `CREATE VIEW` sentence it has a `...` after, just to show you that you should replicate the structure for all the tables....

Comment: Hello again Oscar, i haven't been able to do this. Let me explain to you again what i want to do. I have 3 table with users from diferents locations and i would like to join them in one single table to show on a webpage. i dont want to have duplicated records but  instead i would like to have a single record with the multiple locations where this user is. I am sorry to bother you again.... best regards and thanks for all your help...

Comment: Please, add the table definitions in the question and I'll create a sqlfiddle

Comment: i have added the tables as requested. Thank you for helping me @OscarPérez

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be what you are looking for. Build a new table based on the others with one additional field for the origin:

```
create table users as
select name, loginname, macaddress, 'Dresden' as origin from dresden
union all
select name, loginname, macaddress, 'Düsseldorf' as origin from dusseldorf
union all
select name, loginname, macaddress, 'England' as origin from england
...
```

Of course instead of storing the same origin string again and again you should have two tables instead (but using the same technique):

```
create table origins(id int, origin varchar(30));
insert into table origins (1, 'Dresden');
insert into table origins (2, 'Düsseldorf');
...

create table users as
select name, loginname, macaddress, 1 as id_origin from dresden
union all
select name, loginname, macaddress, 2 as id_origin from dusseldorf
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a table with concatenated location strings as follows. Though I recommend better have three separate tables for users, locations and their relation.

```
create table users as
select 
  loginname, 
  max(name) as name, 
  max(macaddress) as macaddress, 
  group_concat(location) as locations
from
(
  select name, loginname, macaddress, 'Dresden' as location from dresden
  union all
  select name, loginname, macaddress, 'Düsseldorf' as location from dusseldorf
  union all
  select name, loginname, macaddress, 'England' as location from england
  ...
);
```